# Simple Web API Controller returning 404

Tags: asp.net, .net

I just created a basic Web Controller in my project. I hit debug and try to browse to /api/duedate and I get a 404. I am new to controllers and have been looking at every tutorial I can find. None of them say I need to add anything more to get this to work.

```
 Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Class DueDateController
    Inherits ApiController

    ' GET api/duedate
    Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
    End Function

    ' GET api/duedate/5
    Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As String
        Return "value"
    End Function

    ' POST api/duedate
    Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String)

    End Sub

    ' PUT api/duedate/5
    Public Sub PutValue(ByVal id As Integer, <FromBody()> ByVal value As String)

    End Sub

    ' DELETE api/duedate/5
    Public Sub DeleteValue(ByVal id As Integer)

    End Sub
End Class
```

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webPages:Version" value="2.0"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add a route.

[Routing in VB](http://forums.asp.net/t/1819836.aspx?RouteTable%20Routes%20MapHttpRoute%20only%20available%20in%20C%20not%20VB)

If you read the last comment in this thread it should show you how to add routing to your app.

Comment: I have MapPageRoute available not  RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute

Comment: Do you have the same imports as he does?  Are you maybe missing a reference?

Comment: I confirmed that I have all the references and imports he does. I've even tried adding additional ones. No luck

Comment: Alright, Intellisense is messed up. It's there just won't recommend it.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + R will refresh the Intellisense Cache.

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone else out and to simplify having to read through that long post. You need to create and modify your global.asax file to include this:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("WebApi1",
                                  "api/{controller}/{id}",
                                  defaults:=New With {.id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional})
End Sub
```